# Converting VBS Script to Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I currently have .vbs files that I double click and run to convert my Excel files to .txt files in the format as output below. I would like to add this as a VBA code snippet so I can create the files right from inside Excel. I have no experience with .VBS so this has proven difficult and I have made no progress.

Does anyone have suggestions or would like to help convert this to VBA?

I appreciate any help.

Thanks,

```
wscript.echo "Process Journal Entries for upload?"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("S:\Accounting\JE60.xlsm")
set myfileFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set myts=myfileFSO.CreateTextFile("S:\Accounting\JE60.txt")
set objWorksheet=objWorkbook.Sheets(1)

introw=1
count=0
Do Until objWorksheet.Cells(intRow, 1).Value = "" 
count=count+1
introw=introw+1
loop

myts.write "G," & objworksheet.cells(6,2).value  & "," & objworksheet.cells(2,2).value & "," & objworksheet.cells(5,2).value & "," &objworksheet.cells(7,2).value & "," &objworksheet.cells(3,2).value & "," &objworksheet.cells(4,2).value & "," & objworksheet.cells(8,2).value & "," & objworksheet.cells(10,2).value & "," & objworksheet.cells(11,2).value & "," & objworksheet.cells(12,2).value & chr(10)    


for i=14 to count

myts.write "D," & objworksheet.cells(i,1).value & "," & objworksheet.cells(9,2).value & "," & objworksheet.cells(i,2).value & "," &objworksheet.cells(5,2).value & "," & objworksheet.cells(i,3).value & "," & objworksheet.cells(i,4).value & "," & objworksheet.cells(i,5).value &"," &objworksheet.cells(i,6).value &"," &objworksheet.cells(i,7).value &"," &objworksheet.cells(i,8).value &"," &objworksheet.cells(8,2).value & chr(10) 

if objworksheet.cells(i,9).value <> "" then
myts.write "A," &objworksheet.cells(i,9).value &"," &objworksheet.cells(i,10).value &"," &objworksheet.cells(i,11).value &"," &objworksheet.cells(i,12).value &"," &objworksheet.cells(i,13).value &"," &objworksheet.cells(i,14).value &"," &objworksheet.cells(i,15).value &"," &objworksheet.cells(i,16).value &"," &objworksheet.cells(i,17).value &"," &objworksheet.cells(i,18).value &"," &objworksheet.cells(i,19).value &"," &objworksheet.cells(i,20).value &"," &objworksheet.cells(i,21).value &"," &objworksheet.cells(i,22).value &"," &objworksheet.cells(i,23).value &"," &objworksheet.cells(i,24).value &"," &objworksheet.cells(i,25).value &"," &objworksheet.cells(i,26).value &"," &objworksheet.cells(i,27).value &"," &objworksheet.cells(i,28).value &"," &objworksheet.cells(i,29).value & chr(10) 

End if

next

myts.close
objExcel.Quit
set objExcel=nothing

' msgbox "Done."
wscript.echo "Done"
```

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty close to VBA as it is. Put the whole thing in a `Sub` / `End Sub` block within a VBA module and debug each error one by one.

The major changes you need to make are:

1) `Set objExcel = Excel.Application` in place of the line you currently have. You don't really need `objExcel` at all but retaining it will minimise the amount of code changes you need to make.

2) If you already have the workbook open then write `Set objWorkbook = Workbooks("JE60.xlsm")`

3) Drop the line `objExcel.Quit` else you'll keep losing your work!

4) Replace `wsript.echo` with `debug.print`.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I ended up changing some of it so that the filename saved to was the workbook name and user selects the directory to save to. Thank you!

Comment: @user3566159 Plus `Dim` your variables appropriately for efficiency and error prevention. Also suggest a variant array on place of the range loop - will greatly improve speed.